# Solution to implementing caching layer in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, caching, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

I have a function with 1 argument (date) which encapsulates 1 query like

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM tbl
 WHERE some_date_field BETWEEN param_date - INTERVAL '0 1:00:00' DAY TO SECOND
                           AND param_date
```

What I want to do is to cache somewhere the result of this query with ttl = 1 minute. The cached result should be shared across all sessions, not just current one.

Any proposals?

PS: Yes, I know about oracle function result cache, but it doesn't fit the requirements.
PPS: Yes, we can create 2nd artificial argument with some value like `date in format of yyyymmddhh24mi` so it changes each minute and we're able to use function result cache, but I hope it is a solution which will allow me to hide the caching dependencies inside.

Comment: How about storing it in a type with last updated time?

Comment: @Sathya: and where to store the type itself?

Comment: varrays can be stored in the database, right? @zerkms

Comment: @Sathya: yes. And you propose to replace one query with another? What is the profit then? ;-)

Comment: @Zerkms - True. My assumption was that querying a single record type would be lot faster than your query which looking by your simplified example would be lot more complicated. hence the comments :)

Comment: @Sathya: hehe, no, the original query is simple and has great execution plan. But it is called a lot of times (about 100 per second). I ready to exchange accuracy to performance, but not sure that querying another table will worth it.

Comment: And why do you do a COUNT(\*) query 100 times per second. Is it an existence check? ("if count(*) > 0 then ...")

Comment: @Rob van Wijk: ttl = time to live (ie the result would only be considered "fresh" for one hour before becoming "stale")

Comment: @Rob van Wijk: because this function is a part of a procedure that is invoked by a lot of remote clients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a global application context, and a job with a refresh interval of 1 minute to set the context.

PS: *INTERVAL '1' HOUR* is shorter and more meaningful than *INTERVAL '0 1:00:00' DAY TO SECOND*

Comment: Uhm, isn't a global application context session-dependent?

Comment: I must admit that I haven't used or tested it, but in the documentation it says: "ACCESSED GLOBALLY This clause indicates that any application context set in namespace is accessible throughout the entire instance. This setting lets multiple sessions share application attributes." (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_5002.htm#SQLRF01202)

Comment: @Rob van Wijk: oops, context :-S feeling so dummy, I already use them )) yes, they are shared across all sessions.

Comment: @Rob, thanks this helped me on a similar problem!  My approach was to use dbms_scheduler on some interval to do updates on a table, wasn't aware of the application context.

Comment: @Jeff: I was puzzled by what you meant with your comment, until I upvoted some other answer myself. I hope the unicorns are a temporary joke, though.

Answer (score 4):

You want to cache the result of this query, and share the cache across all sessions. The only way I can think of is to wrap the query in a function call, store the result in a small table. The function will query the small table to see if the count has already been stored within the last 1 minute, and if so, return it.

You would keep the table small by running a job periodically to delete rows in the "cache table" that are older than 1 minute - or better still, perhaps truncate it.

However, I can only see this being of benefit if the original SELECT COUNT(*) is a relatively expensive query.

Comment: +1. Also if the function needs to compute the result, you need to make sure that another session isn't currently computing this same result (this is a multi-user environment). You could use a master table whose pk would be the parameter. The procedure would need a lock on the row where pk=parameter before attempting to refresh the detail table. The master table could store the compute time (which would be needed for the ttl)

Comment: Although the result in this case would fit in one row (hence you wouldn't need a detail table here)

Comment: It might need one row per distinct `param_date`.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp: it is cheap when it is called once. But being called a lot of times it creates some CPU (and IO) loading that I want to decrease (the table, that is fetched in that query, continuously changed, so oracle cannot cache the query efficiently too). In case if we had some sort of shared memory - cache would be much more performant solution.

Comment: @Vincent Malgrat: dog pile is not an issue here. I think that it is better to run COUNT(*) query 10 times (simultaneously) than block other threads.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp: btw, what do you think of my solution given at PPS in the question?

Comment: @zerkms, I think it could work. Would need to be tested - the nice thing about it is that I believe DML on the table would invalidate the cache, so it should always be accurate.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp: oh yes, forgot about that :-( in 11gr2 the dependency management was implemented to be automatic... So - not a good decision for me then (since that table is modified with ~ the same frequency as COUNT() is performed).

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp: thanks and +1 to your answer, but seems like contexts is what I was looking for.